# Wordpress: modify tags before saving a post to database

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, tags, custom-post-type

I am looking for a solution to modify the tags/terms from a post before it gets saved to the wordpress database (as a plugin).
This is needed because the default metabox for the tags/terms is made invisible for some users...

I have done already:
- created a meta_box with a checkbox inside
- read from database if this special tag/term is already set for this post

What i want:
 - depending if the checkbox is unticked, the special tag/term should be removed from database
 - if the user has ticked the checkbox, the special tag/term should be added (not overwrite all tags/terms; just add/append)

```
    $tags = get_the_terms( $post->ID , 'customtagcategory' );
    if($tags) {
        foreach( $tags as $tag ) {
            if ($tag->term_id == '44') {
                $tagavailable = 'true';
                break;
            } else {
                $tagavailable = 'false';
            }
        }
    } else {
        $tagavailable = 'notset';   
    }

    return $tagavailable;
}
```

Any clues which function allows me to not only retrieve this information from database but also gives the possibility to write it back?